# It is all right to compile code inside a virtual machine?

Tags: compilation, virtual-machine

It is all right to compile code inside a virtual machine? Or I will get different code compiling outside of it?

Comment: It will produce the same code because the compiler used to compile the code will be the same as the ones used outside a VM

Comment: yep, @AlexYan is right, I am doing it daily - now Visual Studio performance sucks on the VM, but that's a different issue.

Comment: not only is it "all right" it is common place

Comment: I have compiled Android source inside a virtual Ubuntu machine

Answer (score 2):

There's no inherent problem with compiling code within a VM.  We actually do this at my work to ensure the code we are compiling compiles on a machine with no actual dev work.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what language you are compiling, right?

For instance, you can compile a Java application on any machine and it will run on any computer that has the applicable JRE installed.

Obviously you are not going to be able to run Linux programs compiled in VM directly in Windows.

However, virtualization should have no effect on the compilation process and therefor you should be safe to compile your code inside a VM, as long as the target platform is the same as (or supported by) your virtual platform.

Comment: thats what I was thinking about... I compiled some code under a VM(windows7underUbuntu64) and got diff results from same code compilation directly in Ubuntu64...

Comment: Would be interesting to see some bytecode of a small app that has discrepancies.. although there might be some minor differences I'm guessing it should still run

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly safe to compile in a virtual machine. The difference in code is simply due to compiler optimization.